# Making avi movie from tiff stack in MATLAB using getframe()

Tags: matlab, tiff, avi, movie

I am writing a simple code to convert a tiff stack to a .avi movie. Here is my current code

```
TiffName='Un102319_1466ul_min_3.tif';
filename='movieTest';

for i=1:numel(imfinfo(TiffName))
    imshow(imread(TiffName,i))
    mov(i)=getframe(gca);

end

movie2avi(mov, filename);
```

The imshow() works fine, but the movie shows only the toolbar above the image. It seems that getframe isn't doing what I thought it was supposed to do.

Comment: Try pre-allocating your `mov` structure before you start getting frames.  Try doing this before your `for` loop: `nFrames = numel(imfinfo(TiffName)); mov(1:nFrames) = struct('cdata', [], 'colormap', []);`.  Also, can you post that `tif` file so that I can reproduce on my end?

Comment: I tried the adding the code you suggested, and I got the error "Error using double Conversion to double from struct is not possible. " Also, where can I post the tif?

Comment: Try http://www.files.com or if you have Dropbox, share a public link.

Comment: I also created that struct on my own here and it worked.  Either way, please share the file and I'd like to see what's wrong on my end.  Thanks!

Comment: okay here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/blzsgzp8heoszz1/Un102319_1466ul_min_3.tif

Comment: what if you create the mov structure as @rayryeng proposed and use mov(i).cdata = getframe(gca)?

Comment: @Beth Thanks.  Let me get back to you on why this is happening

Comment: @Beth - Your code worked for me, but I had to slightly change one of your lines of code :)  Answer is posted below.  Good luck!  BTW, the video that I got can be found here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9143086/movieTest.avi - Note that this is **uncompressed**, so use something like VLC to run it

Comment: FYI, from `help movie2avi` in the past few versions of Matlab: "`movie2avi` will be removed in a future release. Use `videowriter` instead." I'm surprised that you're not using `videowriter` given your earlier question.

Comment: BTW, since you appear to already have the stacked TIFF, if you're only using Matlab to output a Movie, you might instead try the open source [ImageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/) instead. It supposedly can [convert a stacked TIFF to a movie](http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=faq:technical:can_i_convert_a_large_stack_into_.avi_.gif_quicktime_without_loading_it) with either an AVI or QuickTime container.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a videowriter object:

```
mov((1:nFrames) = struct('cdata', [], 'colormap',[]);

YourVideo = VideoWriter('MovieName.avi'); % you can add compression options also
YourVideo.FrameRate = 15; % Select frame rate

open(YourVideo);

for k = 1:nFrames

mov(k).cdata = getframe(gca);
writeVideo(YourVideo,mov(k).cdata);

end

close(YourVideo);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote works for me.  My suspicion is your `getframe` call is wrong.  Simply call it **without** `gca`.  You want the **current figure**, not the current axes.

As such:

```
TiffName = 'Un102319_1466ul_min_3.tif';
filename='movieTest';

in = imfinfo(TiffName);
for k = 1 : numel(in)
    imshow(imread(TiffName, k));
    mov(k) = getframe; %// Change here
end

movie2avi(mov, filename);
```

---

This will give you what you want, but `movie2avi` doesn't offer a lot of choices in terms of compression algorithms.  As such, I would recommend you go with the `VideoWriter` approach and take a look at Benoit_11's answer.

Good luck!

Comment: From `help getframe`: "`getframe(H)` gets a frame from object H, where H is a handle to a figure or an axis." The idea is to record just the contents of the axis and not get a movie with an ugly gray border.

Comment: So it turns out that the reason it was displaying the toolbar had something to do with the fact that I was docking the figures as I displayed them. As soon as I undocked them, everything worked smoothly. Anyone know why?

Comment: @Beth: If your code creates a separate figure for each frame (that's what I understand from your comment), that's inefficient and can definitely lead to this issue. You can use the `'Parent'` option of `imshow` to deal with this. Something like `imshow(imread(TiffName,i),'Parent',gcf)` maybe.

Comment: Actually, it has to be an axis handle so : `imshow(imread(TiffName,i),'Parent',gca)`. Also, note that, at least on my computer, `imshow` scales your image by 33% to fit on my 1920px wide monitor so your resultant movie will not have the full resolution of the TIFF. You'll need to use another scheme if that's what you want, but I think that's another question.

Comment: @horchler: sorry if I was unclear. I meant that the video saved was only a video of the toolbar above the figure. I am displaying each frame on one figure, and that figure was displaying correctly. It seems to be that the getframe function is just taking a screenshot of a certain position, so when my figure is docked, it's not in the expected position, and the screenshot is taken of the toolbar above. It may be mildly annoying to leave my figures undocked, but at least I have a way to make the video correctly now.

Comment: @Beth: I can't replicate your issue with a docked figure window either. What Matlab `version` and OS are you using? Does using the `'Parent'` not do anything?

Comment: @horchler: I'm using R2013b and OSX 10.9.4, and using the 'Parent' did not change anything